# guidance for copying contents from .jrn file to .text and delete content in every 1 hour

Tags: c#

I need to develop an application to copy the contents of .jrn file as soon as it is generated in ATM.The generated file name(.jrn) will be saved on the basis of date,What i wanted is,my application should copy the content of .jrn file to one text file lets say "xy.txt" and all of these contents should be deleted in every one hour.I am planning to develop this in .NET platform.Can any one suggest me how can i do it or the steps involved in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I would do some research as the following :

1) You say your application need to copy every 1 hour the content of the .jrn file to a .txt file. That imply you need to run your application as a 'background process'. You will need something like a **Timer**, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

2) In order to copy the content of .jrn to .txt, you will need something like stream and serialization. You will want to *read* the content of the .jrn file, do some *parsing* if you want only one type of information, and then *serialize* what you have extracted to the new .txt file.

Hope that can help.

Comment: No..my application will copy content of .jrn file when ever it gets generated..it may depends on customer transaction..but.these copied contents must be deleted in every one hour

Comment: So clear your .txt file every one hour. To figure out when your .jrn is generated (eg 'modified' here), take a loke at the FileInfo class, it has some properties like LastWriteTime

Comment: actually...new file will be created in folder based on client's transacations...my application should copy this contents from newly generated file to a temporary file....so..how can i search whether new file created or not?...one more question...Should i use windows forms application to develop this? or ...

Comment: You have the same class for directory level : DirectoryInfo, you can monitor what's happening in your directory. Create a Windows Forms application only if you have to parameter some things in your application. For your scenario, you only need a background process IMO

Comment: I think i need to use window service for this,am i right? may i know what is IMO?